# Не проигрывается звуковой файл внутри теста

Tags: java, аудио, юнит-тесты, junit

Проигрываю файл так:

```
public static void play(String filename) {
    FileInputStream fis = null;

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
        AudioStream audioStream = new AudioStream(fis);
        AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    Utils.streamClose(fis);
}
```

Проект тестовый (JUnit 4). Если создаю файл с main и запускаю как Java Application - играет. Если помещаю внутри теста - нет. Исключение не кидает. Что интересно, если запустить тест под отладкой и идти по шагам - то тоже играет (причём если только зайти внутрь play()).

В чём может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку использую только в тестах на windows, то сделал по простому:

```
public static void playByPowerShell(String filename) throws IOException {
    String command = String.format("powershell -c (New-Object Media.SoundPlayer '%s').PlaySync();", filename);
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, плеер запускает отдельный поток для проигрывания. JUnit видит, что тестируемый метод завершился, и переходит к следующим тестам. Когда все тесты выполнены, среда, исполняющая тесты, завершает всю программу, вместе с плеером. Когда вы идете по шагам, плеер успевает что-то проиграть, пока вы держите выполнение тестового метода.

Вам нужно либо найти в API AudioPlayer какой-то способ дождаться завершения проигрывания, либо вставить после вызова `AudioPlayer.player.start(audioStream);` `Thread.sleep()`, чтобы что-то услышать.

Вообще, такой тест - не очень хорошая идея, т.к. в этом тесте вы проверяете в основном работу чужой библиотеки, и это занимает значительное время, а unit-тест должен выполняться максимально быстро.

Также, sun.audio устарел и ужасно документирован, вместо него рекомендуют [javax.sound](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/) или сразу [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html).

Comment: Не, этот вариант я уже продумывал. И ждал, и запускал в отдельном потоке, но в любом случае тест не завершался сразу.

Comment: А на счёт неправильной идеи. Возможно. Там ситуация такая - я тестирую логин. По http обмениваюсь запросами, в результате получаю некий url, который надо открыть в браузере, авторизироваться и мне вернётся callback, который я распарсю, получу нужные поля и завершу логин в тесте. И я как делаю - открываю в браузере этот урлик, сам же в тесте, играю звук (просто для меня) и жду ввода в консоли callback-а, который скопирую из браузера. Выглядит ужасно, но я не знаю другого способа